# Easiest way of converting numpy array with colored pixel map to greyscaled pixel map

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem how convert a numpy array with shape:

```
(N, 128, 128, 3)
```

to shape:

```
(N, 128, 128, 1)
```

Basically I have an image with mask of particular part of real image. This is hold in numpy array with values like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

or

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

I want to convert this array into

```
[0.0]
```

```
[1.0]
```

Comment: if you would get every `(128, 128, 3)` as separated image then you could use `cv2` to convert color from `RGB` to `GRAY`. Eventually you could get `R = data[:, :, :, 0]`, `G = data[:, :, :, 1]`, `B = data[:, :, :, 2]` and do `(R+G+B)/3` but as I know normally programs use proportions like `(0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B) / 3` to calculate better gray color. [Image Processing 101 Chapter 1.3: Color Space Conversion | Dynamsoft Blog](https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/insights/image-processing/image-processing-101-color-space-conversion/)

Comment: It would help if you explained what you meant by `want to convert`. The examples you gave could be "converted" to the output by simply taking a slice, or by averaging, or taking the product, etc. What is the mechanism to get from `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` to `[1.0]`? What should the output be if the input is `[4.0, 123.54, 99.7]`?

Comment: It is only a mask of image part. There are only arrays full of `1.0` or `0.0` So output will also always be `[1.0]` or `[0.0]`

Comment: You can take a slice on that axis. So if `A.shape` is `(N, 128, 128, 3)` then `A[:,:,:,0:1]` will take a slice of each item and have a shape of `(N, 128, 128, 1)`.